# laravel application does not logout but clears user defined sessions

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-4.2

i am working on a social networking laravel application.i am creating a session(organization_id) when user logging each time.

so the strange thing happened is when i closed the browser and shutdown PC and came after 8 or 9 hours , the user is already logged in (it's OK) but the my declared session(organization_id) is null so i get error page.

then i cleared browser cache,cookies,sessions and login again its working fine and issue will occur when application left logged in.

can anyone please help me with this situation.
is it laravel related issue?

PLZ NOTE:when browser is closed and came back to application, it does not create any problem.problem shows when left from application for a day or something.

### my session.php file value are

```
'driver' => 'file',
'lifetime' => 480,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

### session creation

```
Session::put('organization_id', 123);
```

Comment: my first assumption is something in the cookie lifecycle is happening, something is being lost when the browser is closed in the cookie maybe.  but is that even possible. So if not, sounds like you might have the session  being garbage collection (on the server-side) or something on you, after some duration, hinting at your suspicions of it being something in laravels module that handles your sessions. .

Comment: when browser is closed and came back to application, it does not create any problem.